# capture a part of a website with javascript or flash

Tags: javascript, screen-capture

We want to make a website that has kind of a 'photocamera' on it. The ideas is that the user can place this camera somewhere on the website and create a 'screenshot' of it and store it in a database, or send it to the website owner.

Is there any chance to realize this with JavaScript or Flash for all browsers?

Comment: Not with JS or Flash. You'd have to run an instance of a browser or rendering engine on the server. AFAIK, Webkit can run headless but I may be wrong.

Comment: thanks, i found this html2canavs script which can do screenshots in php but i've no idea how there would any chance to select a specific part of the screen and just screenshot this.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not cross browser, but there is a Chrome Plugin at 
[Screen Capture (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg?hl=en)
You can rename the `.crx` to `.zip`. Then extract it and check out how they did the trick.

I'm afraid you have to create custom solutions for the different browsers which is hard. but it sounds not impossible!